# static values of a class are restoring the default values in nextjs

Tags: typescript, class, oop, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to use Nextjs for my project. Here I am trying to store some data in my server because I don't need to store them in a database. For that I am using class/static where I was trying to store those data. but everytime I call them the data restore. The changese of those data restore to the default.

I am trying to fix this issue. How can I handle this. If I can't then is there any other way to handle this? without any cache server.

Comment: where did you want to save it? Looks like you need to write your data to a file instead of using database?